# Trying to build end to end jmeter AWS instance testing architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jmeter, command-line-interface

I am trying to build on demand AWS jmeter(can be any testing tool like SOAP UI, Selenium ) instance to using Jenkins. Not looking for Server client Jmeter distribution architecture.

This is to provide cost effective solution to the spawn on demand jmeter(Not containerization )instance using Jenkins. New instance need JNLP or jenkins agent to establish connectivity with Jenkins Master.[image]

Can some one provide me any documentation and  codes(CLI) to spin up aws instance with or without AMI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to manage instances ([create, launch, shut down, terminate, etc.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html#launching-instances))

Example command would be:

> aws ec2 run-instances --image-id **[your_image_id](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)** --count **how_many_instances_you_want** --instance-type **[desired_EC2_instance_type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)** --key-name **[your_key_pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)** --security-groups **[your_EC2_security_group_name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)**

Make sure that the security group allows the following ports:

- the port you define as `server_port`, by default `1099`
- the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
- the port(s) you define as `client.rmi.localport`

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if your are looking for this kind of setup.

1. Use terraform, infra as code. You will be able to spawn all the resources that are required for your test. The steps will follow like this,
2. Create a jmeter Docker image
3. Push it to ECR
4. Create a Cluster in ECS
5. Create a Task definition
6. Create a service in ECS cluster where it uses the Jmeter image and you can use fargate serverless.

On all the above you can use Jenkins CI/CD where you can trigger you terraform code.